# Getting LDAP running with PHP on 2008 R2

Tags: apache-2.2, php, windows-server-2008-r2, ldap

I'm having trouble getting the php ldap extension running on my web server, which is running 2008 R2.

**Install Notes**

1. Apache: httpd-2.2.16-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi
2. PHP : VC6 x86 Thread Safe (2010-Jul-21 20:06:17) (ZIP)
3. adLDAP.php

**Steps I've taken**

1. Made sure `php_ldap.dll` is in `C:\PHP\ext` (I had to get this from http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46971)
2. Made sure `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` are in `C:\PHP`
3. `C:\PHP` has been added to `PATH`
4. `extension=php_ldap.dll` is uncommented in `php.ini`
5. `extension_dir` is set to `C:\PHP\ext` in `php.ini`
6. ran a `phpinfo();` the correct `php.ini` is being loaded, but ldap is not initialized

I'm really at a loss for what might be happening, when I try and use the extension I get the following error (expected since it didn't load):

```
exception 'adLDAPException' with message 'No LDAP support for PHP. See: http://www.php.net/ldap' in C:\Website\hmis\adLDAP.php:338 Stack trace: #0 C:\Website\hmis\login.php(10): adLDAP->__construct() #1 C:\Website\hmis\index.php(2): require_once('C:\Website\hmis...') #2 {main}
```

Does anyone have any advice on what might be going wrong? Thanks.

**Edit:** So it seems like php_ldap.dll is missing from 5.3.3 VC6 builds, I got my copy from a 5.3.1 VC6 build. Could that be causing issues? I'm using apache so I can't use the official VC9 PHP builds, should I try to use ApacheLounge builds? I don't think it should be necessary because I got LDAP working with the official builds for 5.3.1

**Edit 2:** So the other thing I've tried is completely removing the `php_ldap.dll` from `C:\PHP\ext` . I get the exact same error as before, and apache doesn't crash as I would expect it to. Shouldn't it not be able to start with a missing extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on a 2008 box. My problem turned out to be a result of incorrect dll's. Probably worth making sure they are from the thread-safe version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I've made sure I have the 5.3.3 dll and I"m still running into the same problem

Comment: Never mind that, you were right, at first I was using the 5.3.1 version, then I upgraded to the 5.3.3 nts version. Now I am using the 5.3.3 ts version and it works!